# jQuery validation in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation in an asp.net MVC application.
I want to do something in form submission if validation was true.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  alert("test");
})
```

The problem is IE call `$("#myform").submit` before validation checking therefore `alert()` run if validation is true or if not. but other web browser such as firefox, opera, safari. chrome call  `$("#myform").submit` if validation was true.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  if( $(this).valid() ) {
    alert("test");
  }
})
```

alert calling form is valid.
how about this?

Answer (score 0):

What jQuery validation are you using? A plugin, or your own implementation?

Generally when I write my validation script, i do it inside the submit event call. If you can respond with what you're using and how you set it up, we might be able to give you further assistance :).

Comment: jquery.validate.min.js  + jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use onSubmit on the form?

Ex:

```
<FORM 
 ACTION="../cgi-bin/mycgi.pl"
 NAME="testform" 
 onSubmit="return TestDataCheck()"
 >
```